# Clone a specific source from Bitbucket repository powershell

Tags: powershell, bitbucket

Hi all I have written a PowerShell script to clone the repository to my local drive using PowerShell script.

```
Function CloneBitBucket
{
 [CmdletBinding()]
 param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $sourceLocation,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $localPath 
)
 git clone $sourceLocation $localPath
}
CloneBitBucket
```

This is downloading all the available projects, but I would like to clone only a specific project instead of downloading all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Projects per repository

It sounds like you might have multiple projects inside a single repository.

Both Git and Mercurial work much better when each project has its own repository, and neither has good support for cloning just a subdirectory. Consider the following answers.

- [Regarding Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732038/354577):

  > The idea is not to store *everything* in one giant git repo, but build a small repo as a main project, which will reference the right commits of other repos, each one representing a project or common component of its own.
- [Regarding Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929921/354577):

  > you should create multiple repositories, one for each independent project as a start.
  >
  > Mercurial commits are made an a repository-wide level and you cannot checkout just a single subdirectory. This is unlike Subversion which allows you to make in-consistent commits by commiting only some files, but then it also allows you to checkout just a single subdirectory.

I advise you to split your multi-project repository up into multiple single-project repositories. It will save you a lot of headache later.

### Sparse checkout with Git

However, it *is* possible check out just certain subdirectories with Git using something called [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/354577). Note that with this approach *your clone will still contain the entire directory tree*. What changes is the files that are shown in your working copy.

Sparse checkout is a bit of a pain, and in my opinion not a good approach to handling multiple projects inside a single repository, but it's there if you want to use it.

### Cloning a single branch with Git

If you wish to clone only a single *branch* with Git you can use the `--single-branch` and `--branch` options to [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

```
git clone --single-branch --branch some-branch $sourceLocation $localPath
```

I suspect can update your PowerShell function to support a third `$branchName` parameter.

Comment: Hi `Chris` thanks for that, how can I download a branch from PowerShell

Comment: @Dotnet, are you using Git or Mercurial?

Comment: `Chris` I am using Git

Comment: I am confused with `--single-branch --branch some-branch` as you said if I pass $branchname as input then how the script will look like

Comment: `--single-branch --branch $branchname`

Comment: You mean to say `git clone $sourceLocation $localPath --single-branch --branch $branchname`

Comment: @Dotnet, I believe the last two arguments have to be the repository you're cloning (your `$sourceLocation`) and the directory you want to clone into (your `$localPath`), as I've shown in my answer. I have also linked to the official documentation for `git clone`, which you should probably look at. You can also try the command out to see if it does what you expect.